# why is the URL of a react application having "?index" attached to as a search parameter after a route re-loads following an action?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am using a react-router-dom v6  element to handle submitting data from a form.  When I do this the URL changes from localhost:5173 to localhost:5173?index

this is my routing. I pass this array of routes to createBrowserRouter()

```
const routesConfig = [
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <Root />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <Index />,
        action: indexAction,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I stripped down my  component so you can see what it does. It has a single react-router-dom  element in it that just submits - this triggers the 'action' that is used on the index route.

```
import { useActionData, Form } from 'react-router-dom';

export function action() {
  return { foo: 'bar' };
}

const Index = () => {
  const actionData = useActionData();

  const foo = actionData ? actionData.foo : null;

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>index</h3>
      {foo ? <p>{foo}</p> : null}
      <Form method='post'>
        <button type='submit'>submit</button>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Index;
```

Can anyone help me to understand why "?index" is added as a searchParam to the URL only when the path to that child route is declared to be the index route?  Or is it maybe happening for some other reason.

after some debugging and checking paths in my  components to see if they were relative or absolute I narrowed it down to the declaration in this route that it is the index route

```
{
   index: true,
   element: <Index />,
   action: indexAction,
},
```

if I re-write it so that "index:true" is replaced with path:"/" in the route, the url does not have "?index" appended to it when a reminder is added - I think searchParams are being added just because the page has refreshed and re-rendered but it may be something to do with useActionData or even the submission of the new Reminder data to the action for that .

I have made changes to the route so that it is no longer declared as the index route and is instead given a path of "/", and this fixed the problem but it doesn't seem like this would be the correct solution.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the answer:
the reason is to disambiguate nested routes that match the same path as their parent but require different actions to handle  submissions - so you may have a route that resolves to 'Projects' that contains a form and a child route which is identified as an index route which also has a form and this allows them to have different action functions.

```
  {
    path: "/projects",
    element: <ProjectsLayout />,
    action: ProjectsLayout.action,
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <ProjectsIndex />,
        action: ProjectsPage.action,
      },
    ],
  },
]);

<Form method="post" action="/projects" />;
<Form method="post" action="/projects?index" />;
```

[reactrouter.com/en/main/guides/index-search-param](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/guides/index-search-param)